# Apache Ignite Google cloud Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ignite

I deployed apache ignite cluster in google cloud referring [1], but it given class not found error as follows.

[1]. https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/google-cloud-deployment

Error message :

```
2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation

class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:990)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:355)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:387)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:744)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:945)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:724)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:693)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:352)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration#0' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#1efee8e7' of type [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] while setting bean property 'discoverySpi'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#1efee8e7' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kube
rnetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder#1442d7b5' of type [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder] while setting bean property 
'ipFinder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernet
es.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder#1442d7b5' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal
.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration#6e2c9341' of type [org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.K
ubernetesConnectionConfiguration] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration] for bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguratio
n#6e2c9341' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]; nested exception is java.
lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:381)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#1efee8e7' defined in U
RL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.spi.d
iscovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder#1442d7b5' of type [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder] wh
ile setting bean property 'ipFinder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.disco
very.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder#1442d7b5' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/exampl
e-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration#6e2c9341' of type [org.apache.ignite.
kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassExce
ption: Cannot find class [org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration] for bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.Kubern
etesConnectionConfiguration#6e2c9341' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml];
 nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubern
etesIpFinder#1442d7b5' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]: Cannot create 
inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration#6e2c9341' of type [org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionCo
nfiguration] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.ignite.kub
ernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration] for bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration#6e2c9341' defined i
n URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundExc
eption: org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration] f
or bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration#6e2c9341' defined in URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/mas
ter/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.Kuberne
tesConnectionConfiguration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:401)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1438)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1383)
        ... 38 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=https://r
aw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/modules/kubernetes/config/example-kube-persistence-and-wal.xml]
Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.
```

As the error message says no libraries in class path. Is there any issue in docker image or have any issue in deployment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to add `ignite-kubernetes` module to classpath (libs/)

Answer (score 1):

That's the old documentation. The new, updated ones are better: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/gke-deployment

But, in short, you're missing the `ignite-kubernetes` module. In your deployment/stateful-set YAML file you need something like this:

```
  containers:
    # Custom pod name.
  - name: ignite-node
    image: apacheignite/ignite:2.10.0
    env:
    - name: OPTION_LIBS
      value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http
    - name: CONFIG_URI
      value: file:///ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Working perfect with 2.10.0 docker image

Answer (score 0):

Update apacheignite/ignite docker version to 2.10.0